# How to return Java Exception info to jQuery.ajax REST call?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I have some jQuery code that makes a REST call to a Java back end.  Processing of the back end function could encounter an Exception.  What is the best way to get this information back up to Javascript?  In a test I caught the exception in Java and set the HTTP status code to 500.  This caused the $.ajax error handler to be called, as expected. the args to the error handler don't really contain any useful information.  I'd ideally like to propagate the Exception.getMessage() string back to the error handler somehow, but don't know how.

```
function handleClick() {
    var url = '/backend/test.json';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            alert("it worked");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR);
            alert(textStatus); // this comes back as "error"
            alert(errorThrown); // this comes back as "undefined"
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with jquery or ajax but with your application backend. What are you using? Servlets? JSP? Spring-MVC?

Comment: What about the jqXHR object that you get as an argument to your error handler? Can't you read the body of the response -- or a header -- from there?

Answer (score 11):

I was able to send a custom error message (java String) back to a jQuery based client this way. I think my custom message can be replaced with the exception info you want/need

### in Controller:

```
public static void handleRuntimeException(Exception ex, HttpServletResponse 
                                          response,String message) {
        logger.error(ex);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        response.getWriter().write(message);
        response.flushBuffer();
}
```

### In client/javascript (called from ajax on error event)

```
displayError:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
   if(jqXHR.responseText !== ''){
        alert(textStatus+": "+jqXHR.responseText);
    }else{
        alert(textStatus+": "+errorThrown);
    }  
}
```

Hope this helps/

Comment: As pointed out by @mikerobi, I think `sendError` is more appropriate instead of `setStatus`. I believe there are some additional under-the-hood operations performed by `sendError` that `setStatus` doesn't do.

Answer (score 4):

Use the servlet response object's `sendError` method, which lets you set the status code and status text message.

[Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int,%20java.lang.String%29)

[Example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0400__Servlet/ServletResponseSendError.htm)
*EDIT*

The [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) parameter gives you access to all of the response information including the status message.

`jqXHR.statusText` will give you the status message passed in to the `sendError` method.

If you need more than a short message you can write data to the response output and get that from `jqXHR.responseText` or `jqXHR.responseXML`.

Comment: That is a good suggestion and something I had considered.  Only problem is that the error string doesn't seem to be sent up to the jQuery error handler at all.  That's what I'd like to get implemented.

Comment: @user411180, it's there, your not looking in the right spot.  Hopefully my edit will clear things up.

Comment: `If you need more than a short message...` Why? Does something go wrong if the second string parameter to `sendError` is too big?