# Spring 3.2 DeferredResult - How to set status code for error response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

Spring Web 3.2 comes with a `DeferredResult` class for asynchronous request processing. It has a `setErrorResult` for providing an alternative response if something goes wrong, but no option to supply a http error code.

Surely it must be possible to control the http response code for failed requests.. How do I do that using the new Spring api?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/) for `setErrorResult` method says the following:

> Set an error value for the DeferredResult and handle it. The value may
>   be an Exception or Throwable in which case it will be processed as if
>   a handler raised the exception.

I suppose by setting an `Exception`, you may trigger an exception handler that returns the code you desire.

Answer (score 2):

```
deferredResult.setErrorResult(new Exception());
```

This will always set the HTTP response code to 500. For finer control HttpServletResponse.setStatus seems to work.

This will work with [user411180's client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252573/how-to-return-java-exception-info-to-jquery-ajax-rest-call).

```
public DeferredResult<List<Point>> getMessages(@RequestParam int reqestedIndex, 
            final HttpServletResponse response) {

    final DeferredResult<List<Point>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
    deferredResult.onCompletion(...);
    deferredResult.onTimeout(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            deferredResult.setErrorResult("Explanation goes here.");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_PARTIAL_CONTENT); //or SC_NO_CONTENT
        }
    });

    longPollRequests.put(deferredResult, reqestedIndex);
    return deferredResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception that you pass as the argument to `setErrorResult` can be
annotated with `@ResponseStatus`. e.g. create an exception class of your own:

```
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
  class NotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
     // add your own constructors to set the error message
     // and/or cause. See RuntimeException for valid ctors 
  }
```

Then in your code use it with the constructor you have created, for example:

```
  deferredResult.setErrorResult(new NotFoundException(reason, cause));
```