# How to get error response in Ajax?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I am trying to add data to a cart(using) Ajax jQuery, now I have added a primary key constraint and I want when the constraint is violated in get the error message in jQuery:

```
 function add()
       {
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
        $('#addtocart').submit(function() {
           //$('#add-button').prop('disabled',true);
    var user = $('#user').val();
           var pid = $('#pid').val();
        $.ajax({
        type:       "post",
        url:        "/devilmaycry/register?action=addtocart",
        data:       {pid:pid ,user:user},
        success:    
                   function() 
                    {
                          alert("Item has been added to cart");
                },
                  error:
                     function() 
                    {
                          alert("Item already present in the cart");
                } 
              });
     return false;
   });

        });
       }
```

The error function never runs, the functionality in the DB is running fine but I don't see the error message in Ajax.

Here is Java code:

```
public int addintocart(String user,int pid)
{
 try
  {
   conn = obj.connect();
   String sql="insert into cart(userid,product_id,quantity)  values(?,?,?)"; 
   ps1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps1.setString(1,user);
        ps1.setInt(2,pid);
        ps1.setInt(3,1);

         ps1.executeUpdate();

  }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception k)
    {
        k.printStackTrace();
    }

   return x;
 }
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: How do you define "error" here? Some real Java exception/error or already_present_in_cart error?

Comment: error means the `error:` function in jquery code.... how do i make it run ?

Comment: And where are you sending response back?

Comment: The error is not some key violation or some back-end error.It's a problem with the ajax error.You have to send response and check if it's an error

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the error back as a servlet response from Java. Here is an example: [How to return Java Exception info to jQuery.ajax REST call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252573/how-to-return-java-exception-info-to-jquery-ajax-rest-call)

Also, you are missing some parameters in the ajax error function. It might be another problem. Check out http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ You should evaluate the error and present the appropriate message.

Comment: this is not answer, you could write comments, if you say he is missing some parameters you need to point that.

Comment: @maytham I think he covers the point of sending a response back.That more or less covers the answer.

Comment: @maytham I'm sorry, I am new at this. Can you point me to some guidelines? I saw this on my phone and wanted to help, but typing on it is a pain.

Comment: @JamiesonRhyne do not be sorry it is fine, typically I wont answer if it is only link to duplicate question, I will just write comment and flag the question as duplicate. but if JoeyRohan think this is ok, it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

That error code wwill never work. the onerror event of AJAX only runs when connection cannot be established or URL does not exist. You have to return something from your the server indicating success or faliure.

I would do it this way.

PHP(convert this code to JAVA):

```
if(success){
    die(1);
} else {
    if(notyetincart){
       die(0);
    } else {
        die(2);
    }
}
```

Then Jquery coded:

```
function add()
       {
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
        $('#addtocart').submit(function() {
           //$('#add-button').prop('disabled',true);
    var user = $('#user').val();
           var pid = $('#pid').val();
        $.ajax({
        type:       "post",
        url:        "/devilmaycry/register?action=addtocart",
        data:       {pid:pid ,user:user},
        success:    
                   function(response) 
                    {
                          if(reponse==="1")
                          alert("Item has been added to cart");
                          else if(reponse==="0")
                          alert("Item could not be added to cart");
                          else alert("Item already present in the cart");

                },
                  error:
                     function() 
                    {
                          alert("Item could not be added to cart due to poor network connection");
                } 
              });
     return false;
   });

        });
       }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @RichardMcFriendOluwarr this is not php question, this is an Java question?